# Problem with nginx install, no idea how to fix

Tags: linux, nginx, systemd, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install a nginx server on my laptop (Ubuntu 18.04), for my website.

I followed a tutorial, and it was working well, then I tried to make some modification on website, and there were some errors (it was about my GitHub repository I was trying to clone on `/var/www/html`, not nginx).

For fixing it, I stopped nginx with `SIGKILL` on all PID's.

Then I have no idea why but there were some problems, and I removed the `/etc/nginx` repo (Yes, it was really a bad idea, I know...)

When I try to restart/start nginx now, I get this error :

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for 
details.
```

I tried many things I found on internet but it always refers to the configuration file that I deleted.

Is there a way to completely remove nginx from my computer and re-install it properly? I think it's the best option; or a way to fix it, if you know that?

Comment: "and I removed the `/etc/nginx` repo"  - why do you refer to the `nginx` configuration files directory as `repo`?

Comment: the configuration file is in the repo /etc/nginx, and I removed the entire repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## re-installing nginx

> Is there a way to completely remove `nginx` from my computer and re-install it properly? I think it's the best option. Or a way to fix it, if you know that?

To remove and re-install the [`nginx`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nginx) (virtual) package, you can use [apt](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt.8.html#description) on Ubuntu (being a Debian derivative):

```
apt remove -y nginx

apt install -y nginx
```

## analyzing service failure

> Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with 
>   error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for 
>   details.

You may consider issuing:

```
journalctl -u nginx
```

to see the exact reason for the error.

`-u` stands for and accept the name of a [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) unit and `.service` suffix can be omitted being the default type for units.

## copying configuration files

You can clone the [nginx](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/nginx) source package upstream [nginx](https://salsa.debian.org/nginx-team/nginx) repository on Debian Salsa as:

```
git clone git://salsa.debian.org/nginx-team/nginx
```

and copy over the `conf/` directory contents to `/etc/nginx` with:

```
cp -rv nginx/conf/* /etc/nginx/
```

`-r` is for recursive (subdirectories, if any) copy and `-v` is for verbosity (output of copied files on console screen)

Comment: Already tried, it changes nothing :/ 
I remove nginx/apt autoremove and reinstal, when i'm trying to start nginx after the reinstal, the same error appears

Comment: Does re-installing the package create `/etc/nginx` directory and the `nginx.conf` file in it?

Comment: It creates the directory but there is not nginx.conf file in it

Comment: Please see the updated answer and report if it helps.

Comment: You might also have ran `dpkg --reconfigure nginx` or a special switch of `apt` i am not yet aware of that would consider installing configuration files as well on package re-installation. You are welcome and I am glad that it helped.